# Windows tokens manipulation

Tags: penetration-test

I am creating a demo of the infamous windows tokens manipulation.

the scenario I am using is as follows:

A single PC connected to the domain controller. 2 users are signed in the DC through that computer. A regular user and a domain admin.

I am using nishang to enumerate tokens but no tokens are found.

How can I create tokens in order to use them?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the tokens are probably there, but you don't have permissions to see them.

Comment: Ok understood. The user i am using is a local admin. I thought that would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying this greatly, the tokens you're looking for are going to be attached to processes created by interactive logons. If you've got a domain admin logged on interactively, you've got domain admin tokens.

I'm not familiar with how Nishang enumerates tokens, but I've had pretty good experiences with Meterpreter. Maybe give that a go?